# Is vector division defined or not? What is this?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is from the book "linear algebra done right" 2nd edition, chapter 3, exercise 4.

Basic assumptions in the book:F denotes R or C. V denotes a vector space over F.

> Suppose that T is a linear map from V to F. Prove that if u ∈ V is not
>   in null T, then V = null T ⊕ {au : a ∈ F}.

When I was checking the solution, I saw this part that said:

> If v ∈ V, then   $v = (v-\frac{Tv}{Tu}u) + \frac{Tv}{Tu}u$
>
> Note that
>
> $T(v-\frac{Tv}{Tu}u)=Tv-\frac{Tv}{Tu}Tu=0$

and so on...

Well, I understand that $Tv,Tu∈F$. So we can do the division. But my question is: what if we change F to some arbitrary vector space? Can we still do that?
like $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{av}{bv}$ where v∈V, a,b∈F and b≠0.

Comment: No, you can only do division in a field, not in an arbitrary vector space.

Comment: Obviously not, it only works for functionals. Even if division of vectors was defined (as, say, for quaternions) the result will not be factorable from under $T$ since it is only linear with respect to scalars.  And if $T$ is not a functional then $F$ is more than one dimensional so the complement of ${\rm null\,} T$ can not be spanned by a single vector either.

Comment: Changing $F$ to an arbitrary vector space doesn't make sense because $F$ is supposed to represent the field of scalars that the vector space $V$ is taken over.  And division of vectors is not defined.

Comment: It is a norm, should be $\frac{\|Tv\|}{\|Tu\|}$. Bad notation but should be inferred from the last equation.

Comment: @GilbertoLópez No, it shouldn't. $Tu$-s are scalars, so the norm would reduce to the absolute value. And the last line of the computation won't work if values are replaced by absolute values.

Comment: Oh I see, anyway, you can treat a field as a vector space, but cannot mix the concepts, $Tu$ is an element of the field, yes, but seen as a vector space, and $\frac{Tv}{Tu}$ is scalar division, but those things are vectors, the operation is defined over fields, not vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

No. Division is only permitted among elements of $F$ (see definitions of fields and vector spaces). And I'm sure you know that here $T(u)\neq 0$. You can even solve this question without division. First use the fact that $dimV = dim(NullT)+dim(RangeT)$. $dim(RangeT)$ is either $0$ or $1$ according to the linear map $T$. If zero, then the statement is true as $V = NullT$ and $\{au\}$ is empty. If $dim(RangeT)=1$ then assuming $V$ is $n$-dimensional, we have a basis $\{v_1,...,v_{n-1}\}$ of $NullT$, which we can extend to a basis of V by introducing the element $u$, as $u\notin NullT$. The rest should be clear.